# What are the values and directions of electron spin for 45 degree to previous measured direction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I suspect it is an easy problem for those who know quantum mechanics well. But web search and reading several links it found could not help. As of now I got only that at orthogonal direction to one that has been measured spin is superposition of "up"/"down" with equal values. But what is the formula for arbitrary direction and in particular what is the value for 45 degrees direction to just measured direction? Half of 45? Maybe a chart showing (presumably, I guess it can be visualized so) how distribution of up/down changes from all "up" to 50% "up" when angle goes from 0 to 90?

Answer (score 0):

A good starting representation for understanding spin is the matrix one:

$$ |\uparrow\rangle = \left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right]$$
$$ |\downarrow\rangle = \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\1\end{array}\right]$$

which are the states with $S_z = \pm \frac 1 2$. The $z$-axis is arbitrary, but is traditional, as it works well with spherical harmonics, which works with spherical coordinates, which have choses to make $z$ the "special" axis.

You can look up the Pauli matrices in the $(x, y, z)$ basis. They form a vector, so that the spin-axis-projection operator on a random direction $\hat n$ is:

$$\sigma_n = \vec\sigma\cdot\hat n = 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}n_z&n_x-in_y\\n_x+in_y&-n_z\end{array}\right]$$

If you're new to spin, it may seem weird that the spin and spacial vector live in different spaces...so spin matrices and euclidean vectors don't really talk to each other--which is not a mathematically rigorous statement.

The eigen-spinor of $\sigma_n$ with eigenvalue +1 (so spin projection $\frac 1 2$ on the $n$-axis) is (up to an arbitrary phase):

$$ |\uparrow\rangle_n =
\left[\begin{array}{c}\cos{(\theta/2)}e^{-i\phi/2}\\\sin{(\theta/2)}e^{+i\phi/2}\end{array}\right]$$

where $(\theta, \phi)$ are the polar and azimuthal angle of $\hat n$.

The probabilities of spin up/down depend only on the polar angle:

$$p(\uparrow) = \cos^2(\theta/2) $$
$$p(\downarrow) = \sin^2(\theta/2) $$

So if you choose the $x$-axis ($\theta_x = 90^{\circ}, \phi_x=0$):
$$ |\uparrow\rangle_x =
\left[\begin{array}{c}\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}\\\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}\end{array}\right]$$

which is 50% spin up and 50% spin down.